# Does the towel touching the day 1 starter and absorbing the liquid matter?

Tags: baking, bread, dough, food-science, sourdough

On day 1, I’ve noticed the towel is wet.  Does the towel absorbing anything from the starter ruin the starter and prevent it from reaching its desired outcome?

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine.  I would suggest using a container that creates more space between the cover and the starter.  That way you won't have a mess to clean each time.

Comment: Let alone the problem when the starter really gets active and climbs out of the jar...